# Change Default Save To Directory For Content Downloaded From Apps

Tags: settings, downloading, file-management

I've been looking all over and could only find information on changing the directory for the camera or for changing from the internal storage to an external SD card.

What I am trying to figure out is how to consolidate my downloads, specifically all of my images, into one nice folder. For example, anything downloaded from Chrome is saved to the folder "Download" while everything I save from Reddit is Fun is saved to "Pictures." This drives me nuts when I am trying to send somebody one of these pictures and my Gallery is very cluttered. It would be great if there were an app and/or procedure that allowed me to specify which folder the content from each app should be downloaded into.

I am on a rooted SGH-T889, 3.0.36 Perseus Kernel, running stock 4.1.2.

Comment: Not that it matters on a global scale, but Reddit is Fun released a new update that allows the user to specify the directory. 1 app down, 20+ to go! lol

Answer (score 2):

For reddit is fun, you can set it to "Use external browser" in Settings, it should open Chrome and files will be saved in the same location. Takes a little bit longer to open links though.

For Chrome, there seems to be no way to change download location but [creating a symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). This may require root, and your picture directories will still be displayed separately in your Gallery.

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to weigh my options against jumping through hoops and using the External Browser, or having my files be slightly unorganized... Lol